# Populating ruby hash:- by hash of hashes with array values

Tags: ruby

My DB response looks like this:

```
response = [
{id: 1, name: Kassandra, group: Sparta, role: Mercenary}
{id: 2, name: Alexios, group: Sparta, role: Mercenary}
{id: 3, name: Herakles, group: Athens, role: Champion}
]
```

My method:

```
def get_group_details
  grouped_details = []

  response.each do |key|
  key['group'] = key
  grouped_details.push(key)
  end

end
```

Which results in **stack_level_too_deep** error, on looking I believe it's leading to an infinite loop... 
What I am trying to manipulate the response to send to UI:

```
 response: [
   Mercenary: {
         [{id: 1, name: Kassandra, group: Sparta, role: Mercenary}, {id: 2, name: Alexios, group: Sparta, role: Mercenary}]
}
  Champion: [{id: 3, name: Herakles, group: Athens, role: Champion}]
]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `key` is a hash, initially `{id: 1, name: Kassandra, group: Sparta, role: Mercenary}`, so `key['group'] = key` replaces the value of `'group'`, here `'Sparta'`, with the same hash. The next statement creates an infinite loop. Incidentally, this is not really a Rails question as it doesn't matter where `response` came from, so you should remove the "rails" tag. Moreover, I doubt anyone would search on any of the tags other than "ruby", so I suggest you make that the only tag. (More tags is not necessarily better.)

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland Removed the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#group_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) to group the hashes based on a specific key's values:

```rb
response.group_by { |h| h[:role] }
# =>
{
  "Mercenary": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Kassandra",
      "group": "Sparta",
      "role": "Mercenary"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Alexios",
      "group": "Sparta",
      "role": "Mercenary"
    }
  ],
  "Champion": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Herakles",
      "group": "Athens",
      "role": "Champion"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! That's awesome!